# csv.DictReader only read in certain rows

Tags: python, multithreading, csv, dictionary

Is there a way to read in certain rows of a .csv file when using the csv.DictReader function in Python?

For example if you only want to load in the 10th-20th rows of a .csv file **without loading in the entire dataset** first.

I have several .csv files with 200 million rows each, containing 10 field_name data entries -hence why I'm using the DictReader and not simple csv.read().

Here is a simple example of my current method:

```
import csv
from tqdm import tqdm

field_names = ['A','B','C']

IDs = []
with open(file_1) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f,field_names,delimiter=',')
    row_count = 0
    for row in tqdm(reader): 
        row_count+=1
        ID = row['A']
        if ID not in IDs == True: 
        IDs.append(ID)
```

You can see why this would be slow for 200 million rows to iterate through and any further conditions or processing within the loop just slows it down massively.

So it would make sense to iterate through groups of rows and then multi thread them to save time.

Things I've considered:

- Using pandas csv reading routine (you still have to load in the
  entire dataset at the start)
- Iterating through rows as in my example
  code, logging the number of rows, and then reloading the rows in multi threaded
  batches.
- Using a generator rather than an iterator (eg. see [ThreadPool and Pool for parallel processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51611735/threadpool-and-pool-for-parallel-processing))

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate` to generate row indices, and `break` the loop when the index reaches your target:

```
IDs = set()
for i, row in enumerate(reader):
    if i > 9:
        IDs.add(row['A'])
    elif i > 19:
        break
```

Note that you can make `IDs` a set instead of a list for much better efficiency in obtaining unique IDs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I assume this method still iterates through the lower rows  to get to the range of rows you want? I can see this being a problem when having to iterate through 90% of the dataset before reaching the final say 10 rows if that makes sense

Comment: On a side note, I have implemented your idea of using a set instead of appending to a list -thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Yes, reading through the lower rows is a must because there's no other way to count the number of lines, each ending with a newline character, without actually reading every character. What I show you would at least still help when your target row is near the beginning of the file.

Comment: That makes sense..I guess that means there's no way around either:

1.Iterating through the dataset line by line but not storing in memory or 
2. Loading in the entire dataset and then selecting the lines from memory

Comment: Right. The option 1 is certainly preferrable though.