# Why does creation of multiprocessing.Pool object try to connect to 127.0.0.1: [port] and fails to do so?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612823/7402089), but when I try to execute that code as is it gives me output with errors.

Code from that answer (to simplify for you):

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
# from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
import time
import multiprocessing as mp


def my_function(x):
    return x + 1


pool = ThreadPool(4)
my_array = np.arange(0, 1e6, 1)

t1 = time.time()
# results = list(tqdm(pool.imap(my_function, my_array),total=len(my_array)))
pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)  # Generally, set to 2*num_cores you have
res = pool.map(my_function, my_array)
print("Time taken = ", time.time() - t1)
```

I expected that code to work, but for some reason it gives me this output:

```
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 54842
NoneType: None
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 54854
NoneType: None
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 54858
NoneType: None
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 54861
NoneType: None
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 54865
NoneType: None
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 54868
NoneType: None
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 54872
NoneType: None
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 54877
NoneType: None
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 54898
NoneType: None
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 54901
NoneType: None
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 54914
NoneType: None
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 54918
NoneType: None
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 54929
NoneType: None
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 54932
NoneType: None
```

Why the heck it tries to connect to some ports at all and why does it fail to do so even when the firewall was off? How do I make it work?

Comment: running your example does not raise such errors on my machine, is it possible that to simplify you accidentally omitted the lines that actually cause the problem..?

Comment: The only thing, that I changed from that code is I commented unused module `tqdm`.

Comment: well, works perfectly for me both with and without. maybe it has something to do with your IDE..? did you try running it using `python` cmd directly from terminal?

Comment: `RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.`

Comment: Are you developing this on Windows? I think you might be falling afoul of the issue regarding compensating for Window's not-forking [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14175401/11639518)

Comment: Yes, it's on Windows. So this `multiprocessing` module is simply not working under Windows?